# ember-data - rerference class in template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am writing an ember-cli addon and I want to allow the user of the component generated by the addon to use an ember-data class as a source.

For example if I have:

```
var Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  // attrs
});

export default Employee;
```

How can I then reference this in a template like this;

```
{{x-autosuggest source=Employee destination=chosenEmployees searchPath="fullName" minChars=0}}
```

The above will be undefined.

In the bad old day of globals, I could have used App.Employee:

```
{{x-autosuggest source=App.Employee destination=chosenEmployees searchPath="fullName" minChars=0}}
```

How can I reference the class in the template when using es6 modules?

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass an instance of such class instead of the class name itself? Users can instantiate it on the route. Moreover, they'd want to extend it or even include it as a Mixin.

`{{x-autosuggest source=employeeInstance destination=chosenEmployees searchPath="fullName" minChars=0}}`